# Select multiple lines based on field value

Tags: sql, oracle, case, union

I need to produce a query that will output something like:

```
NAME                GRADE    SUBJECT
Smith, Shirley          3        ELA
Smith, Shirley          3          M
Jones, John             5        ELA
Jones, John             5          M
Jones, John             5        SCI
```

If a student is in grades 5, 8, or 11, the query should produce 3 lines of data per student. Grades 3, 4, 6, 7, 9, 10, and 12 should produce only 2 lines of data.

I have tried using a UNION ALL approach marrying three case statements, but this gives a 'Missing Select keyword' error.  If I remove everything from the first UNION ALL and everything below it, the top portion of the query works just fine on it's own.

What is a better approach to this?

```
CASE
  WHEN s.grade_level IN (3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12) THEN
    SELECT
      s.lastfirst as NAME,
      s.grade_level as GRADE,
      'ELA' as SUBJECT            
END
FROM students s

UNION ALL

CASE
  WHEN s.grade_level IN (3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12) THEN
    SELECT
      s.lastfirst as NAME,
      s.grade_level as GRADE,
      'M' as SUBJECT     
END
FROM students s

 UNION ALL

CASE
  WHEN s.grade_level IN (5,8,11) THEN
    SELECT
      s.lastfirst as NAME,
      s.grade_level as GRADE,
      'SCI' as SUBJECT     
END
FROM students s
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WITH cteSubjects AS (
    SELECT 'ELA'  AS Subject FROM dual
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'M' FROM dual
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'SCI' FROM dual
)

, cteGrades AS (
    SELECT 3 as grade_level
    FROM dual

    UNION ALL

    SELECT  c.grade_level + 1
    FROM
       cteGrades c
    WHERE c.grade_level + 1 <= 12
)


SELECT *
FROM
    cteGrades g
    INNER JOIN cteSubjects s
    ON (CASE
          WHEN g.grade_level IN (5,8,11) AND s.Subject = 'SCI' THEN 1
          WHEN s.Subject <> 'SCI' THEN 1
          ELSE 0
       END) = 1
    INNER JOIN students s
    ON g.grade_level = s.grade_level
```

While Throstens is correct you should probably have lookup and relation tables for grade to subject it can be done without.  you can use Common Table Expression [CTE] to create the subjects, then recursive cte to generate the grades then join them together to get the 2 or 3 subject to grade combination you want and then simply join students to it.

Comment: Great bit of sql - thank you. I had to modify it slightly, the cteGrades AS statement was generating "ORA-32039: recursive WITH clause must have column alias list" which I resolved with cteGrades ( grade_level ) AS (...  I agree that Throsten's answer would be preferred, but we are not always dealing with a database where we can edit the schema, as is my case. I needed to find a sql based solution, not a recommendation on how to change my DB. Matt's solution works great.

Answer (score 0):

It would be way better to put data in tables and not in your query. So there are grades related to subjets? Have a table for this relation then:

**grade_subject**

```
grade  subject
3      ELA
3      M
4      ELA
4      M
5      ELA
5      M
5      SCI
6      ELA
6      M
...
```

The query:

```
select
  s.lastfirst as name,
  s.grade_level as grade,
  gs.subject as subject  
from students s
join grade_subject gs on gs.grade = s.grade_level
order by s.lastfirst, gs.subject;
```